# Objective C bug when converting NsNumber to nsString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

```
NSNumber *abc = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:123];
NSString *number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", abc];
```

The result of `number` is 31619! How to fix it?

Comment: Your `%` specifier needs to match what you pass `stringWithFormat:`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an objective C bug, you are using wrong specifier-

Use -

```
NSString *number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", abc];
```

Comment: Right. An NSNumber is a proper object, thus `%@` can be expected to insert its string value. `%d` expects an integer, which is a primitive type and not an object.

Answer (score 4):

You have to return an intValue:

```
NSNumber *abc = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:123];
NSString *number = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [abc intValue]];
```